# UnauthorizedAccessException, path is directory

Tags: c#

This is my Program.cs class, it should download file from dlink to the same folder from where .exe file was executed, but i get error: `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

I allready know it is because the path is directory, but i dont know how to make it so it will work and do the job.

Tried to google my problem, tried to fix it but nothing worked.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace update
{
    class Program
    {



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Config
            String pname = "Pain v0.2";
            String dlink = "https://pastebin.com/raw/vC44QriZ";
            string title = @"
 .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .-----------------. .----------------. 
| .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. |
| |   ______     | || |      __      | || |     _____    | || | ____  _____  | || |              | |
| |  |_   __ \   | || |     /  \     | || |    |_   _|   | || ||_   \|_   _| | || |              | |
| |    | |__) |  | || |    / /\ \    | || |      | |     | || |  |   \ | |   | || |              | |
| |    |  ___/   | || |   / ____ \   | || |      | |     | || |  | |\ \| |   | || |              | |
| |   _| |_      | || | _/ /    \ \_ | || |     _| |_    | || | _| |_\   |_  | || |              | |
| |  |_____|     | || ||____|  |____|| || |    |_____|   | || ||_____|\____| | || |   _______    | |
| |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |  |_______|   | |
| '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' |
 '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------' ";
            // ---------- Do not touch here if you do not know ----------
            Console.Title ="Pain";
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
            Console.WriteLine(title);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to start downloading files.");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("Downloading new Files...");
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            String key = wc.DownloadString(dlink);
            String path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            System.Net.WebClient Dow = new WebClient();
            String patch = (path);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(patch);
            Dow.DownloadFile(key, path);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine(pname + " Succesfully downloaded / updated!");
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to close this window.");
            Console.ReadKey();


        }

        }
    }
```

Errors:
UnauthorizedAccessException

Comment: The most likely cause is that your application doesn't have permission to write to the directory it's located in?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverFlow. The file you trying to download doesn't have write permission, right click your file to download and give admin or other permissions to file and problem going to be solved

Comment: You use `Dow.DownloadFile(key, path);` where `String path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();`. As you said you already know that it is a directory, why haven't you tried to append a filename to the path?

Comment: @Neijwiert Because it is for more people, and the name of folder where it was executed from can be different.

Comment: @MertAkkanat Hello, file that should be downloaded is a .zip file, how should i do that? Thanks.

Comment: @WorTex I understand, but that still doesn't change my question. Have you tried to do something like `Dow.DownloadFile(key, Path.Combine(path, "myFileName.zip"));`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
 String key = wc.DownloadString(dlink);
            String path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            System.Net.WebClient Dow = new WebClient();
            String patch = path;
            Directory.CreateDirectory(patch); // Create Directory
            Dow.DownloadFile(key, System.IO.Path.Combine(path,"pain.zip"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer on my questions! It worked nicely. Have a good day :)

Comment: I wonder how does this work, doesn't it try to create an already existing folder? I would consider changing it into `String patch = path + @"tempDownload\";`

Answer (score 0):

By looking at you problem i feel may be you need to open the directory first.
To make you understand imagine it in a way as you provide a username and password to a website and then you can use it.
I suppose there should be a password to the directory.